# How to standardize the placement of the $ char in strings

Tags: r, regex

I have strings with amounts of dollar. The dollar character `$` though is inconsistently placed either before or after the amount and/or either with or without whitespace in-between:

```
x <- c("$749", "12$", "555 $", "$ 1.50", "$ 66,198")
```

I'd like to standardize the placement of `$` such that it consistently occurs immediately before the amount. To this end I've been using `sub` and backreference in this way:

```
sub("([^$\\s]*)(\\$)", "\\2\\1", x) # or: sub("(.*)(\\$)", "\\2\\1", x)
[1] "$749"     "$12"      "$555 "    "$ 1.50"   "$ 66,198"
```

The result is only partially successful as there is still a whitespace char in-between in the last two strings. I can get rid of these by using *nested `sub`*:

```
sub("\\s", "",  sub("([^$]*)(\\$)", "\\2\\1", x))
[1] "$749"    "$12"     "$555"    "$1.50"   "$66,198"
```

Now the result is the one desired. But isn't there a more direct regex, one that does not require the detour via nested `sub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
paste0("$", gsub(" |\\$", "", x))
# [1] "$749"    "$12"     "$555"    "$1.50"   "$66,198"
```

If you want to rely solely on regex

```
sub("(.*?)(\\$)", "\\2\\1", gsub("\\s", "", x))
# or 
gsub(".*?(\\d+[.,]*\\d*).*", "$\\1", x)
```

Comment: Nice, the last one is the kind of solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work using readr package:

```
x <- c("$749", "12$", "555 $", "$ 1.50", "$ 66,198")
paste0('$',parse_number(x))


[1] "$749"   "$12"    "$555"   "$1.5"   "$66198"
```

Comment: Nice. But I'm specifically interested in a regex solution involving `sub` as the underlying issue (how to place substring X relative to substring Y) is far more general and as soon as non-numerical data are concerned cannot be addressed using `parse_number`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using only sub:

```
x <- c("$749", "12$", "555 $", "$ 1.50", "$ 66,198")

x <- sub(pattern = ' ', replacement = '', x = x, fixed = TRUE)
x <- sub(pattern = '$', replacement = '', x = x, fixed = TRUE)
x <- paste0('$',x)
```

Comment: That's three steps. I was asking for a one-step solution. But still nice job ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can only be one `$` char ans only max. two non-whitespace chunks in these currency only strings, you can use a single `gsub` coupled with `trimws`:

```r
x <- c("$749", "12$", "555 $", "$ 1.50", "$ 66,198")
trimws(gsub("(.*)(\\$)|\\s+", "\\2\\1", x))
## => [1] "$749"    "$12"     "$555"    "$1.50"   "$66,198"
```

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/pW2JVN) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WuxOB5/1).

**Regex details**

- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, as many as possible
- `(\$)` - Group 2: a `$` char
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces.

The `$` is swapped with the text before it and then any whitespaces after `$` are removed. Due to the nature of these strings you have, this will work, only trailing whitespaces will need trimming, hence the use of `trimws`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more answer, based on @Sindri's answer but slightly more compact:

```
sub(".*?([0-9.,]+).*", "$\\1", x) 
[1] "$749"    "$12"     "$555"    "$1.50"   "$66,198"
```